# Is there a way to cancel execution of method in cancelled task?

Tags: c#, wpf, task, cancellation

I have a problem, that I could not find any answear yet. And this is my first project with use of threading and Tasks. When my task is cancelled, it keeps executing time consuming method.

Right now I have not idea how to stop execution of the method  together with the task.

Below is a loop, that runs tasks. Every single task is running a `ParseHorseData` method, that runs also several other methods. Execution of them takes sometimes a lot of time.

After the task is cancelled, before `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` is completed, it takes a lot of time.

So, as in the question, is there a way to cancel execution of method in cancelled task?

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
int loopCounter = 0;
int taskCounter = 0;

//for all races in the file
for (int i = 0; i < _allRaces.Count; i ++)
{
    int j = i;

    if (TaskCancellation == true)
    {
        break;
    }

    Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            loopCounter++;

            ProgressBarTick("Requesting historic data", loopCounter, _allRaces.Count, 0);

            //if the race is from 2018
            if (_allRaces[j].RaceDate.Year == 2018)
            {
                Category = _allRaces[j].RaceCategory;
                Distance = _allRaces[j].RaceDistance.ToString();

                //for all horses in the race
                for (int h = 0; h < _allRaces[j].HorseList.Count; h++)
                {
                    HorseDataWrapper horse = new HorseDataWrapper();


                    //TIME CONSUMING
                    horse = ParseHorseData(_allRaces[j].HorseList[h], _allRaces[j].RaceDate);
                    _allRaces[j].HorseList[h] = horse;
                }
            }

            taskCounter++;

            if (loopCounter >= _allRaces.Count)
            {
                ProgressBarTick("Testing on historic data", taskCounter, _allRaces.Count, 0);
            }
        }
    }, _tokenSource.Token);

    tasks.Add(task);
}

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    //
}
finally
{
    _tokenSource.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You didn't show us the time consuming method.... You should pass your cancellationtoken into that, and check it periodically and throw an exception/abort if it is cancelled. Or atleast check it inside that inner loop, before doing the next iteration of the loop. At the moment your code only has a chance to cancel after that whole loop is run.

Comment: Well, add the `CancellationToken` as parameter to the parser. So you can check IT there also and stop the execution/return.

Comment: Thsnks guys, I found some another walk over of the problem, but both of you inspired me. I had already `if (TaskCancellation == true)` condition in my `for` loop. Loops in method called by task are taking most of the execution time. After pressing cancellation btn, not only `CancellationToken` is trigerred, but instead of passing `ct` parameter to the methods, also in their loops I use `if (TaskCancellation == true)` to `break` them. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to cancel execution of method in cancelled task?

All cancellation is cooperative. The method being executed must pass the `CancellationToken` into the methods that it calls, and either:

1. Periodically poll for cancellation using `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`. This approach is more appropriate for CPU-bound loops.
2. Take an action on cancellation using `Register`. This approach is more appropriate for interfacing with non-`CancellationToken`-based cancellation systems.

In this case, it sounds like polling is appropriate. I strongly recommend polling via `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` and not `IsCancellationRequested`, because when a task is canceled, it should throw an `OperationCanceledException` when `await`ed. This is how the calling code knows it has been canceled.

Example:

```
Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
  while (true)
  {
    _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    ...
       //for all horses in the race
       for (int h = 0; h < _allRaces[j].HorseList.Count; h++)
       {
          _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
          HorseDataWrapper horse = new HorseDataWrapper();
          horse = ParseHorseData(_allRaces[j].HorseList[h], _allRaces[j].RaceDate);
          _allRaces[j].HorseList[h] = horse;
       }
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: In my example Im also catching `A task was canceled.`. Should it be not enough? And in your pattern, it should not be `if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` ?

Comment: Yes, you should catch `OperationCanceledException` when the task is canceled. No, `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` only throws if a cancellation is requested, so doing the extra check isn't necessary.

Comment: Allright, it was tested and it worked. With your idea right now it is throwing exceprion for cancelled tasks. Previously it was throwing exception only for the token. Thanks!

Comment: This is old question, but can I ask you one more thing? In my case (from the question), I am using `Task task = Task.Run(async () =>` in `for` loop to create loads of paralel Tasks. Is it a proper approach?

Comment: @bakunet: If possible, I would split up the parallel work from the asynchronous work. TPL Dataflow is good for this, or if you want a simpler producer/consumer queue, Channels is the best modern approach.