# How should I use Task.Run in my code for proper scalability and performance?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await, task-parallel-library

I started to have HUGE doubts regarding my code and I need some advice from more experienced programmers.

In my application on the button click, the application runs a command, that is calling a `ScrapJockeys` method:

`if (UpdateJockeysPl) await ScrapJockeys(JPlFrom, JPlTo + 1, "jockeysPl"); //1 - 1049`

`ScrapJockeys` is triggering a `for` loop, repeating code block between 20K - 150K times (depends on the case). Inside the loop, I need to call a service method, where the execution of the method takes a lot of time. Also, I wanted to have the ability of cancellation of the loop and everything that is going on inside of the loop/method.

Right now I am with a method with a list of tasks, and inside of the loop is triggered a `Task.Run`. Inside of each task, I am calling an awaited service method, which reduces execution time of everything to 1/4 comparing to synchronous code. Also, each task has assigned a cancellation token, like in the example [GitHub link](https://github.com/przemyslawbak/Horse_Picker/blob/190f4549375c9e499c393dc2f3b734a0b802dd8a/Horse_Picker/ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs#L1657):

```
public async Task ScrapJockeys(int startIndex, int stopIndex, string dataType)
{
    //init values and controls in here
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = startIndex; i < stopIndex; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            LoadedJockey jockey = new LoadedJockey();

            CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            if (dataType == "jockeysPl") jockey = await _scrapServices.ScrapSingleJockeyPlAsync(j);
            if (dataType == "jockeysCz") jockey = await _scrapServices.ScrapSingleJockeyCzAsync(j);

            //doing some stuff with results in here

            }, TokenSource.Token);

        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        //
    }
    finally
    {
        await _dataServices.SaveAllJockeysAsync(Jockeys.ToList()); //saves everything to JSON file

        //soing some stuff with UI props in here
    }
}
```

So about my question, is there everything fine with my code? According to [this article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html):

> Many async newbies start off by trying to treat asynchronous tasks the
>   same as parallel (TPL) tasks and this is a major misstep.

What should I use then?

And according to [this article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html):

> On a busy server, this kind of implementation can kill scalability.

So how am I supposed to do it?

Please be noted, that the service interface method signature is `Task<LoadedJockey> ScrapSingleJockeyPlAsync(int index);`

And also I am not 100% sure that I am using `Task.Run` correctly within my service class. The methods inside are wrapping the code inside `await Task.Run(() =>`, like in the example [GitHub link](https://github.com/przemyslawbak/Horse_Picker/blob/190f4549375c9e499c393dc2f3b734a0b802dd8a/Horse_Picker/DataServices/ScrapDataServices.cs#L566):

```
public async Task<LoadedJockey> ScrapSingleJockeyPlAsync(int index)
{
    LoadedJockey jockey = new LoadedJockey();
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //do some time consuming things

    });

    return jockey;
}
```

As far as I understand from the articles, this is a kind of anti-pattern. But I am confused a bit. Based on [this SO reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56187088/11027921), it should be fine...? If not, how to replace it?

Comment: What is the reasoning for creating one task per loop, instead of a single task for all loops?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias when they run parallelly, it cosumes approximately 1/4 of time when running synchronously, at least in this case and on my machine.

Comment: I see. So your objective is not only scalability, but performance as well. Do an experiment and add this line of code `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);` before `Task.WhenAll`, to see if you get an even greater performance boost.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias with `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);` it took three times longer to execute tasks from loop than without this. Also at some cases some percentage of tasks throws timeout exceptions with this.

Comment: Aha. I guess that the ScrapServices can't handle so many concurrent requests. You should probably actively throttle the parallelism of the tasks, and not leave it to the heuristics of the thread pool scheduler. Here are some links for achieving the throttling: [Approaches for throttling asynchronous methods in C#](https://blog.briandrupieski.com/throttling-asynchronous-methods-in-csharp), [Implementing a simple ForEachAsync, part 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I will take a look. Also my biggest concern was that am I using `Task.Run` correctly for async wrapping or not? After reading these articles I had some doubts: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html, https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html

Comment: What type of code is running inside `ScrapSingleJockeyPlAsync`? Is it CPU intensive or IO intensive? Is it calling a service hosted at a remote machine, or everything is running in a single machine?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias `ScrapSingleJockeyPlAsync` is crawling through HTML documents and their content. Mostly HTML calls consumes time.

Comment: These HTML documents are located in a local hard drive, or there are web requests involved?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias they are websites. Sorry for not specifying. I use to get them `HtmlAgilityPack`

Comment: Aha. So I expect that your workload will be mostly IO intensive. I mean that most of the time your code is waiting for a web response to complete, and comparatively less time is doing actual processing of the results. You could achieve better scalability by not having a thread waiting during each request, and instead use the [`WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstringtaskasync) method. You could even store the responses inside a `BlockingCollection`, and consume them sequentially in a single worker task.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yeah, **Stephen Cleary** just gave similar idea. I think to give it  a try and to rebuild my methods. Also using of `Parallel.For` looks promissing as **mm8** suggested, just I will read articles from your links first, because there was something about `Parallel` class.

Comment: Throttling may be critical not only from a scalability perspective, but also to avoid overpressing the websites and tempting their admins to block your IP address. 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias In my original attempt application was also sending multiple requests in parallel tasks to the website, and noone complained (˵ ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°˵)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understand from the articles, this is a kind of anti-pattern.

It is an anti-pattern. But if can't modify the service implementation, you should at least be able to execute the tasks in parallel. Something like this:

```
public async Task ScrapJockeys(int startIndex, int stopIndex, string dataType)
{
    ConcurrentBag<Task> tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();
    ParallelOptions parallelLoopOptions = new ParallelOptions() { CancellationToken = CancellationToken };
    Parallel.For(startIndex, stopIndex, parallelLoopOptions, i =>
    {
        int j = i;
        switch (dataType)
        {
            case "jockeysPl":
                tasks.Add(_scrapServices.ScrapSingleJockeyPlAsync(j));
                break;
            case "jockeysCz":
                tasks.Add(_scrapServices.ScrapSingleJockeyCzAsync(j));
                break;
        }
    });

    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        //
    }
    finally
    {
        await _dataServices.SaveAllJockeysAsync(Jockeys.ToList()); //saves everything to JSON file
                                                                   //soing some stuff with UI props in here
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks really interesting. I will try it now. But anyway, I am able to change service implementation. I was just wondering, that is it correct? (second code sample from the question, complete code here: https://github.com/przemyslawbak/Horse_Picker/blob/190f4549375c9e499c393dc2f3b734a0b802dd8a/Horse_Picker/DataServices/ScrapDataServices.cs#L566)

Comment: How to implement `ScrapSingleJockeyPlAsync` depends on what the method actually does. Is it really asynchronous by nature? Otherwise it should return a `LoadedJockey` synchronously.

Comment: It is not asynchronous by nature. But other guys answering and commenting here suggests, to use a `WebClient` async method, and later on I can parse it with `HtmlAgilityPack` (taht I used originally). Also yours `Parallel.For` looks promissing to use in VM instead of `Task.Run`, what you and **Stephen Cleary** are not recommending.

Comment: @bakunet: If the methods calls out to a REST API or similar it is indeed asynchronous and then you don't need to involve `Task.Run`.

Comment: Here is written, that it is not recommended to use `Parallel.ForEach` for IO bound work. As I belive, it is the same for `Parallel.For`: https://blog.briandrupieski.com/throttling-asynchronous-methods-in-csharp

Comment: If you want to make several API calls in parallel, it makes perfect sense to use `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach`. Again, it all depends on your requirements and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Understand. Currently I expect 20k - 150k calls to the service class from each loop.

Answer (score 4):

On the UI side, you should be using `Task.Run` when you have CPU-bound code that is long enough that you need to move it off the UI thread. This is completely different than the server side, where using `Task.Run` *at all* is an anti-pattern.

In your case, all your code seems to be I/O-based, so I don't see a need for `Task.Run` at all.

There is a statement in your question that conflicts with the provided code:

> I am calling an awaited service method

```
public async Task<LoadedJockey> ScrapSingleJockeyPlAsync(int index)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //do some time consuming things
    });
}
```

The lambda passed to `Task.Run` is not `async`, so the service method cannot possibly be awaited. And indeed [it is not](https://github.com/przemyslawbak/Horse_Picker/blob/190f4549375c9e499c393dc2f3b734a0b802dd8a/Horse_Picker/DataServices/ScrapDataServices.cs#L586).

A better solution would be to load the HTML asynchronously (e.g., using `HttpClient.GetStringAsync`), and then call `HtmlDocument.LoadHtml`, something like this:

```
public async Task<LoadedJockey> ScrapSingleJockeyPlAsync(int index)
{
  LoadedJockey jockey = new LoadedJockey();
  ...
  string link = sb.ToString();

  var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(link).ConfigureAwait(false);
  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
  doc.LoadHtml(html);

  if (jockey.Name == null)
  ...

  return jockey;
}
```

And also remove the `Task.Run` from your `for` loop:

```
private async Task ScrapJockey(string dataType)
{
  LoadedJockey jockey = new LoadedJockey();

  CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

  if (dataType == "jockeysPl") jockey = await _scrapServices.ScrapSingleJockeyPlAsync(j).ConfigureAwait(false);
  if (dataType == "jockeysCz") jockey = await _scrapServices.ScrapSingleJockeyCzAsync(j).ConfigureAwait(false);

  //doing some stuff with results in here
}

public async Task ScrapJockeys(int startIndex, int stopIndex, string dataType)
{
  //init values and controls in here

  List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
  for (int i = startIndex; i < stopIndex; i++)
  {
    tasks.Add(ScrapJockey(dataType));
  }

  try
  {
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    //
  }
  finally
  {
    await _dataServices.SaveAllJockeysAsync(Jockeys.ToList()); //saves everything to JSON file

    //soing some stuff with UI props in here
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note, that I started to use `Task.Run` to create paralel tasks, to make execution of the loop 4x faster. But I belive, that idea to use `Parallel.For` might fix the problem. It makes a big sence to use `HttpClient` and later on to parse returned string with `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Comment: @bakunet: I recommend re-running those timings with a properly asynchronous (`HttpClient`-based) solution.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I will do like that. I will have to rebuild whole service, but it is my fault to build it not modual. At least long time I will remember my lesson about Tasks and Runs.